# python Selenium Webdriver works in root but not in non-root account

Tags: python, selenium

I have one python selenium scraper.
That works fine in root user but need to run it in non-root account
Sever is centos

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
display.start()
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2})
chromeOptions.add_argument(f'user-agent={useragent}')
chromeOptions.headless = True
chromeOptions.add_argument("--headless")

chromeOptions.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
chromeOptions.add_argument("--no-first-run")
chromeOptions.add_argument("--no-service-autorun")
chromeOptions.add_argument("--no-default-browser-check")
chromeOptions.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
chromeOptions.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
chromeOptions.add_argument("--disable-plugins-discovery")
chromeOptions.add_argument("--incognito")
chromeOptions.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chromeOptions.add_argument("disable-infobars")
chromeOptions.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chromeOptions.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
chromeOptions.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=45447')
path = os.path.abspath("account-data1/account_3")
chromeOptions.add_argument("user-data-dir=" + path)
chromeOptions.add_argument('--proxy-server={}'.format(proxy))

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    ChromeDriverManager().install(),
    options=chromeOptions,
    desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
)
```

I always get this error message when running it in non-root

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable
```

[image]

Could you possible assist me?

Comment: did you find the solution to your problem?